# Bigquery event analytics join in subselect statement

Tags: subquery, left-join, google-bigquery

I am attempting to return a query result from bigquery that returns the number of events that occur by session.  I have been referring to the following article:

http://developer.streak.com/2013/11/using-google-bigquery-for-event-tracking.html

The database schema is pretty simple 
     [sessionId, eventType, createdAt]
The returning result set would be similar to an event workflow in google analytics.  Something like 
     [sessionId, num_event1, num_event2, ...]

The approach is to generate sub queries by event type and timestamp and then create additional subqueries that join the results from each of the event subqueries. I am able to do Step1, step2, step3 subqueries in isolation:

```
SELECT COUNT(first_event_timestamp) AS number_first_events,
       COUNT(second_event_timestamp) AS number_second_events,
       COUNT(third_event_timestamp) AS number_third_events
FROM

(SELECT eventUid AS eventUid1,
        createdAt AS timestamp1
 FROM [events_table]
 WHERE eventType = 'first-event') step1,

 (SELECT eventUid AS eventUid2,
        createdAt AS timestamp2
  FROM [events_table]
  WHERE eventType = 'second-event') step2,

 (SELECT
    eventUid as sessionId3,
    createdAt as timestamp3         
  FROM
    [events_table]         
  WHERE
    eventType = "third_event") step3
```

Adding steps1_2, steps1_2_3 is where i am hitting a wall.  I get an error that the dataset name is missing from the table.  Here is the full query:

```
SELECT COUNT(first_event_timestamp) AS num_first,
       COUNT(second_event_timestamp) AS num_second,
       COUNT(third_event_timestamp) AS num_third
FROM (SELECT
             sessionId
             first_event_timestamp,
             second_event_timestamp,
             third_event_timestamp
      FROM steps1_2_3
      GROUP BY sessionId),

      (SELECT
            sessionId AS sessionId1,
            createdAt AS timestamp1         
         FROM
            [events_table]         
         WHERE
            eventType = "first_event") step1,           (SELECT
            eventUid AS sessionId2,
            createdAt AS timestamp2         
         FROM
            [events_table]         
         WHERE
            eventType = "second_event") step2,       (SELECT
            eventUid AS sessionId3,
            createdAt AS timestamp3         
         FROM
            [events_table]         
         WHERE
            eventType = "third_Event") step3,         (SELECT sessionId1,
                    timestamp1,
                    IF(timestamp1 < timestamp2, timestamp2, NULL) AS timestamp2
             FROM
                  (SELECT sessionId1,
                          timestamp1,
                          timestamp2
                   FROM step1
                   LEFT JOIN step2
                   ON sessionId1 = sessionId2) ) steps1_2,  (SELECT sessionId1 as sessionId,
              timestamp1 as first_event_timestamp,
              timestamp2 as second_event_timestamp,
              IF(timestamp2 < timestamp3, timestamp3, NULL) as  third_event_timestamp
       FROM
            (SELECT sessionId2,
                    timestamp2,
                    timestamp3
             FROM steps1_2
             LEFT JOIN step3
             ON sessionId1 = sessionId3)
             ) steps1_2_3
```

The ideal result set would look something like the following:
sessionId   num_first_event num_second_event     num_third_event
S1              1             null                null
S2              2               3                 null
S3              4               5                 6

My first question is whether it is possible to join in subqueries steps1_2, steps1_2_3 ?

Alternate approaches to achieving a events like work flow in bigquery, instead of counting the number of timestamps?

Any tip or suggested documentation is greatly appreciated
Additionally, thank you for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT
  sessionId,
  SUM(eventType = 'first-event') AS number_first_events,
  SUM(eventType = 'second-event') AS number_second_events,
  SUM(eventType = 'third-event') AS number_third_events
FROM [events_table]
GROUP BY sessionId
```

Comment: did you have chance to make it work? or still issue?